# Entity Framework User Roles One to One Relationship instead of Many to Many Relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

By default Asp.Net is providing Many-to-Many relationship between the tables AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, AspNetUserRoles. Here I want to change these relationships from `(Many-to-Many)` to `(One-to-One)` between AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles only then want to remove AspNetUserRoles using Entity Framework Code First.

I tried with the following code but it representing the error.`The item with identity 'ApplicationRole_Users' already exists in the metadata collection.
Parameter name: item`

I am using Entity Framework Code First

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
   new public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RoleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public virtual ApplicationRole ApplicationRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the ApplicationRole Model

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole() : base() { }


    public ApplicationRole(string name, string description) : base(name)
    {
        this.Description = description;
    }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my ApplicationDBContext class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{        
    //public virtual IDbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(): base("PHELeadContext")
    {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (modelBuilder == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");
        }


        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");

        EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser> table =
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");

        table.Property((ApplicationUser u) => u.UserName).IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().HasMany<ApplicationUser>((ApplicationRole u) => u.Users);            

        EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserLogin> entityTypeConfiguration =
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey((IdentityUserLogin l) =>
                new { UserId = l.UserId, LoginProvider = l.LoginProvider, ProviderKey = l.ProviderKey }).ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");

        EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserClaim> table1 = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");

        // Change these from IdentityRole to ApplicationRole:
        EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationRole> entityTypeConfiguration1 = modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");
        entityTypeConfiguration1.Property((ApplicationRole r) => r.Name).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

My  Questions is.. Is it possible to change the relationship between meta-tables of Asp.Net for `AspNetUsers`, `AspNetRoles`, `AspNetUserRole`?